# base_url() and 403 error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-403

In HTML view, css link code looks like this:

```
<link href='www.jedendzien.pl/assets/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

but my browser is showing adress with double domain adress

> www.jedendzien.pl/www.jedendzien.pl/assets/css/style.css

so i'm getting 403 error. I create link by

```
<link href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

and in config.php i'm setting:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.jedendzien.pl/';
```

In my XAMPP serwer everthing works fine but problem is appearig only on hosting server.

If i change `$config['base_url']    = ''` then adress looks and works ok but i still have problem with 403 error.

My .htaccess in root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Try `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.jedendzien.pl/';`

Comment: Thansk, that solved problem with double domain but 403 error is stiil. Look at this example:
www.jedendzien.pl ->
pure html, without css and js ->
link www.jedendzien.pl/uzytkownik/rejestracja ->
403 error ->
refresh ->
403 error ->
cleaing cookies ->
refresh ->
register form ->
submit ->
403 error...

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden). This indicates to some server bad configuration. Check or remove .htacces file to these resources.

Comment: I've got only one .htaccess file and it's in root.

Answer (score 1):

Change permission of assets/css/style.css to 644

Change base url as follows

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.jedendzien.pl/';
```

Or If you have a secure url,Then

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.jedendzien.pl/';
```

Change .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thans, i hope that will help. It's working but i've tested it with new, empty project in CI (no more time at work). Later i'll add more cotrollers, models and views with jpg files and then we'll see :-)

Comment: We are doing the same thing for the last few years

Comment: it's problem with session. When i add session in autoload file problem is again. Without session it's ok but it's required so i need session in my project.

Comment: I don't think,session can cause this problem.Because you are setup only css path.That css is loading only browsers.not in the server.http://www.jedendzien.pl/assets/css/style.css i can access this file from brawser

Comment: But problem is only when i'm using session. Without loaded session libraries everything css and js are loading fine. Check my site now. I've deleted session library from autoload configuration file. It's working but i can't make login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72462/discussion-between-shijin-and-bejkrools).

Answer (score 0):

For absolute url you should include protocol, it may be relative like this:

```
<link href='//www.jedendzien.pl/assets/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Comment: OK, but i don't understand why base_url() works on hocalhost and why i still get 403 error?
Example: www.jedendzien.pl -> pure html, without css and js -> link www.jedendzien.pl/uzytkownik/rejestracja -> 403 error -> refresh -> 403 error -> cleaing cookies -> refresh -> register form -> submit -> 403 error...

Comment: @Bejkrools maybe you just dont have required permissions on files.  `chmod` should fix this. Search for that to get more information.

Comment: Using FileZilla i changed chmod to '777' for each file in application, system and assets folder. Still 403 error.

Comment: but when i made another index.php (not in CI) in root, and i included file.php from application/controllers/ then it was OK. No 403 error... i don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htacces content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just empty the base_url(); in config.php file.
And copy the text of .htaccess from the .htaccess file of codeigniter 3 from www.codeigniter.com.